# How to Add X axis Padding in chart js Line Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, chart.js

I drawn a Line graph using chart js. it works well but problem is it will start all the lines from 0 but i need some padding between graph line and axis line it. I need like

[image]

I need this Gap ( Red Marked ). How can i achieve this??

Comment: Provide your code, please

Comment: code something similar to this one https://jsfiddle.net/vz4qhqpw/154/

Answer (score 2):

From [**the fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/gqfkyj7s/1/) you provided, A tricky way will be to push in `$scope.labels` and `$scope.data` a `null` in first position:

```
$scope.labels.unshift('');
$scope.data[0].unshift(null);
$scope.data[1].unshift(null);
```

A start you had:

[image]

And you will have:

[image]