# ChartJs - Adding padding after Y- Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, chart.js

I am using chart js 2.7 .I need to add padding after Y-Axis.Means i need a gap before the start and end of the graph. I need to bring the labels inside the x-axis line. I found a similar question below.

[How to Add X axis Padding in chart js Line Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932278/how-to-add-x-axis-padding-in-chart-js-line-graph)

But it provides a solution by adding null values. Is there any other solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add to your options:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                padding: 100
            }
        }], 
    }
}
```

Working jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/vz4qhqpw/2664/